# VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available

Tags: virtualbox, hardware-acceleration, vt-x

I have a dell inspiron 1525 note book with Win7. I am trying to install Win8 on Virtualbox.

But I am getting the error:

> VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.

How can I eanble hardware acceleration on my Inspiron 1525?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system](http://superuser.com/questions/597121/vt-x-amd-v-hardware-acceleration-is-not-available-on-your-system)

Answer (score 3):

As we can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron_1525) the Inspiron 1525 can contain one of many CPU's ranging from a lowly [Celeron 540](http://ark.intel.com/products/30774/Intel-Celeron-Processor-540-1M-Cache-1_86-GHz-533-MHz-FSB), through a [Pentium Dual-Core T2330](http://ark.intel.com/products/32432/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T2330-1M-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB) and on up to a [Core 2 Duo T8300](http://ark.intel.com/products/33099/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T8300-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz-800-MHz-FSB).

As you can see there is three series of processors that could have been used in the laptop, all of those labeled and Intel Celeron or Intel Pentium Dual-Core certainly do not support VT-x instructions (can be confirmed on the [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/) website).

The Core 2 Duo range however appears to support VT-x instructions from the [T7250](http://ark.intel.com/products/31728/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7250-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) upwards ([T7250](http://ark.intel.com/products/31728/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7250-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB), [T8100](http://ark.intel.com/products/33916/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T8100-3M-Cache-2_10-GHz-800-MHz-FSB), [T8300](http://ark.intel.com/products/33099/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T8300-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)). So unless your laptop contains one of these processors I'm afraid VT-x hardware acceleration is not available to you.

If you have a CPU not listed on my source, feel free to check it on [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/). If you do have one of these however and it is simply not working you will need to look at the BIOS of the laptop (albeit they tend to be pretty bare on Dell machines).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this Intel tool to tell you what features your processor supports:

[Intel® Processor Identification Utility](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/sb/CS-014921.htm)