# VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

While installing an OS, I am getting an error similar to:

`VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.`

This should happen if my computer does not supports `SLAT`.  Later I found that my computer supports `SLAT` and `EPT` here is a screenshot:

[image]

But, I am getting this error while starting to boot the OS:

[image]

I am running Windows 7, any ideas?

Comment: Have you confirmed virtualization is enabled within bios?

Comment: i'm afraid cause there is no such option for enabling virtualization  under **Advanced BIOS Options** .. in bios settings ...?

Comment: What type of device are you running e.g. desktop, laptop, model etc... Processor type/model would be very helpful.

Comment: Desktop computer,Windows 7(32-bit) Pentium dual core e5300

Comment: Did a quick search and found similar issues with VBox and the e5300. Enabling virtualization will be key. Some solutions suggest updating the bios. Can you confirm you have the latest?

Comment: Digging a little deeper suggest that proc may not support VT-x. http://ark.intel.com/products/35300. It will depend on your specific model.

Comment: many thanks for that...not sure but this is my bios status: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EKLKE.png

Comment: Not sure how old your board might be, but given it's running a bios from 2009, there may be a good chance there's an update available.

Comment: ok, i will try it.

Answer (score 49):

VT-x/AMD-V support gets disabled for VirtualBox if you have Hyper-V installed. It gets enabled again when you uninstall Hyper-V. You can do that from an elevated command prompt by typing:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Comment: Thank you, mine was working until it wasn't. I removed Hyper-V by going to Control Panel, clicking Programs and Features, clicking Turn Windows features on or off, expanding Hyper-V, and unchecking it.

Comment: Hyper-V is silently installed when you install the Windows Phone Emulators or SDK.

Comment: Hyper V "consuming" AMD-V at boot, without ANY VMs setup, is absurd. I installed Win Phone Emulator quite some time ago, must not have used VBox since then. Getting this message, spending an hour trying to resolve, and ultimately discovering this is the cause, is tiring. Onward march...

Comment: @Sully I think that happens because that part of Hyper-V probably cannot be started up later on demand. It has to be at the very beginning of kernel initialization.

Comment: You don't have to uninstall/reinstall HyperV to fix this problem.  If you need HyperV for phone emulators (like I do) you can just setup new boot options using bcdedit. See my answer under this question for more info: http://superuser.com/questions/698478/error-vt-x-amd-v-hardware-acceleration-not-available-on-your-system-while-tryi/997101#997101

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your CPU doesn't support the VT-x feature, as others have stated. As Joshua pointed out, the Intel website will help you determine the capabilities of your CPU. Specifically you should check the [Ordering/Spec page](http://ark.intel.com/products/35300#ordering), since different revisions of the same processor may have different features.

Basically if your E5300 isn't the SLGTL Spec, then it doesn't support VT-x. The only way to be sure is to find out your Spec Code, either from the box it was packaged in or physically looking at the CPU. You can also try programs such as [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) or [Intel® Processor Identification Utility](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/sb/CS-014921.htm) which will tell you if VT-x is available, but I think only if the option is enabled in BIOS.

Updating your BIOS wouldn't necessarily solve the problem either, because the CPU would still have to have the VT-x feature. Now if you update your BIOS, and there is still no option available for enabling VT-x or hardware virtualization under the CPU settings, then most likely your CPU doesn't support the feature.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should ALWAYS check the Intel Processor Documentation website ARK.INTEL.COM to see what your CPU supports. In this case, the Intel E5300 does not support Virtualization features. See this link:

http://ark.intel.com/products/35300

The utility you are running also shows, albeit not very clearly, that you do not have those capabilities. The dashes (-) indicate that the feature is not available, whereas if you had an asterisk (*) they would. See the following link for reference.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/use-coreinfo-to-determine-processor-capabilities/4937

It should still be able to run virtual machines, however it will be significantly slower than if you had VT support.

Comment: well, the config. shows that it do: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z49X0.png ... any idea?

Comment: @MaxPat. - Intel specifications sheets don't lie.

Comment: @MaxPat. You are mistaken. The readout shows dashes (-), whereas if you had the capabilities, it would show asterisks (*). See the link for reference: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/use-coreinfo-to-determine-processor-capabilities/4937

Comment: Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

A BIOS update has caused the virtualization technology to be disabled in BIOS for me, which resulted in the above error.

Re-enabling the option in BIOS resolved the isue.

PS For AMD CPUs, the option is called SVM and is located deep under Advanced CPU Core settings or something like that.