# Windows 8.1 Pro restarting in VirtualBox boot from ISO (virtualization enabled)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 Pro X86 on a VM with VirtualBox. My OS is LinuxMint 17 Cinnamon. Everything is set up properly except for the fact that I can't asign more than 1 CPU to it in settings. Not sure if it's because of this but when booting the VM from the ISO file I get an error and the VM keeps restarting.

http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-how-to-install-windows-8-1-on-virtualbox-guest-additions-download-iso-file

It is worth mentioning that I'm also getting an error when I first start the VM:

> VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system.
>   Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail
>   to boot without it.

While my issue is the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/597121/vt-x-amd-v-hardware-acceleration-is-not-available-on-your-system), the difference is that my processor **does** support VT ([link](http://ark.intel.com/products/52220/Intel-Core-i3-2310M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_10-GHz?q=2310m)) and I **do** have it enabled in BIOS. My online searches have so far been fruitless and I'm starting to reach the end of the rope with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** After reading another thread (link in comment) I've also tried the following changes in the BIOS but still nothing:

1. System Configuration > Device Configurations > Virtualization Technology <-- ENABLE this
2. System Configuration > Set Security Level > Data Execution Prevention <-- set to Change
3. System Configuration > Set Security Level > Virtualization Technology <-- set to Change

Comment: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/Why-won-t-my-ProBook-4530s-64-bit-run-a-64-bit-VM/td-p/947867

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, after making these changes:

1. System Configuration > Device Configurations > Virtualization Technology <-- ENABLE this
2. System Configuration > Set Security Level > Data Execution Prevention <-- set to Change
3. System Configuration > Set Security Level > Virtualization Technology <-- set to Change

**I also had to remove the laptop battery and leave it like that for awhile.** After starting up the laptop again Windows finally booted from the ISO properly and I could continue with the installation.