# VT-x/AMD-V hardware error when uploading OS to VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

When download Windows 10 onto VirtualBox I get the error 
"VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it."

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Get a CPU that supports it or enable it in your BIOS.

Comment: The only way to fix this error is to enable VT-x.  If you hardware does not support VT-x then you will be unable to enable it.  Typically VT-x is only required to run 64-bit guest operating systems within a 32-bit host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system](https://superuser.com/questions/597121/vt-x-amd-v-hardware-acceleration-is-not-available-on-your-system)